# angular 9 add class on individual element scroll

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I need to add class to an element on an individual element scroll. I created a slackblitz example. I know how to add a class on whole body scroll. But, I need to add on particular element scroll.
In this example I need to add class on scrolling the div#paragraph.

Thanks in advance.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-changeclassonelementscroll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a directive that listens to its host scroll event. Something like would work:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appScroll]'
})
export class ScrollDirective {

  @Input() scrollClass: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  @HostListener("scroll", [])
  onScroll() {
    if (this.el.nativeElement.scrollTop > 20) {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, this.scrollClass)
    }
  }

}
```

I forked your code example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-changeclassonelementscroll-bsngpt)

PS: try to avoid accessing the DOM directly using `document.getElementById`. Always use Angular utilities for that.

Comment: thank you. Any idea, how to remove the added class on scrolling back to top.

Comment: call `this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, this.scrollClass)` on whatever event you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding an event to the paragraph element in your template:

```
<div id="paragraph" (scroll)="onDivScroll()">
```

and then add a function in your component that gets called

```
  onDivScroll(){
    this.document.getElementById('paragraph').classList.add('green');
  }
```

you'll have to add your additional logic as needed, but you should be able to turn the individual element text green this way.

Comment: thank you. Any idea, how to remove the added class on scrolling back to top.